# How can I hide these dots

Tags: css

How can I hide the small dots nearby each picture in IE7 ?
[http://www.sanstitre.ch/drupal/portfolio?tid[0]=38](http://www.sanstitre.ch/drupal/portfolio?tid%5B0%5D=38)

I've tried with `text-decoration:none` and `list-style-type:none` but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you post the relevant `CSS` and `HTML` code for the images or their containers? Are you using `li` or another ordering class to display your images?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because

```
.item-list UL LI {
 ...
 list-style-type: disc;
 ...
}
```

is defined in system.css

Answer (score 27):

Did you put the `list-style-type` in the `ul` or `li`?

It should be: (afaik)

```
ul{ 
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Other than that I used this before:

```
li{
  background-image: url(); /*or link to a blank image*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  padding-left: 12px;
}
```

It's probably not the best way, but it gets the job done :)

**Additionally** try this too:

```
li.class, li.collapsed, li.expanded {
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul {
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always add classes to your elements:

```html
<ul class="hidden">
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar Foo</li>
</ul>
```

Try this:

```css
.hidden {
 list-style-type: none;
}
```

```css
.hidden {
 list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<h3>A simple UL</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar Foo</li>
</ul>

<h3>A hidden one</h3>
<ul class="hidden">
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar Foo</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
  li{
display:inline;
}
```

than dot will not show in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#menu-ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**